# Null Display in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, service, null

Currently I am doing a course from Udemy where I learn Angular and C#, and I got stuck at a point.
Before implenting the pagination I can enter in edit profile of user and I can enter to the page of information of the user when I press the icon of user on card of user.

After implementing the pagination, I cannot get the user, and it is null.

I tried to map as well but it is not working, in the course at this point is subscribe.

Moreover, when I try to create other function that is working in other files, in this file is not working.
Also I tried to create a new file and implement there the functionality (I thought that this maybe will work) , but it is not.

Here is my github link to the repository: https://github.com/Faraon4/DatingApp

PS: this is my first time when I ask a question for help in internet, I guess that maybe it is not correctly asked , but hope that it is understandable

Thank you in advance who will help, because I get stuck here and cannot continue the course